# return instances' id inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
function Bee(name, id, lifespan, hitPoints) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.lifespan = lifespan;
    this.hitPoints = hitPoints;
    Bee.numInstances = (Bee.numInstances || 0) + 1;

    return this;
}
```

inside document ready I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var BEE = BEE || {};

    BEE.QueenBee = new Bee('QueenBee', 1, 100, 8);

    BEE.WorkerBee = new Bee('WorkerBee1', 2, 75, 12);
    BEE.WorkerBee = new Bee('WorkerBee2', 2, 75, 12);
    BEE.WorkerBee = new Bee('WorkerBee3', 2, 75, 12);
    BEE.WorkerBee = new Bee('WorkerBee4', 2, 75, 12);
    BEE.WorkerBee = new Bee('WorkerBee5', 2, 75, 12);

    BEE.DroneBee = new Bee('DroneBee1', 3, 50, 12);
    BEE.DroneBee = new Bee('DroneBee2', 3, 50, 12);
    BEE.DroneBee = new Bee('DroneBee3', 3, 50, 12);
    BEE.DroneBee = new Bee('DroneBee4', 3, 50, 12);
    BEE.DroneBee = new Bee('DroneBee5', 3, 50, 12);
    BEE.DroneBee = new Bee('DroneBee6', 3, 50, 12);
    BEE.DroneBee = new Bee('DroneBee7', 3, 50, 12);
    BEE.DroneBee = new Bee('DroneBee8', 3, 50, 12);

    //$('button').on('click', ba);

    for(i = 0; i < Bee.numInstances; i++){
        console.log(Bee.id === 2);
    };

});
```

my console.log returns 14 false. I want to check/brake the loop and only return each instance that has an ID of 2, hence "Bee.id === 2"

Comment: FYI, an object property can hold only one value. If you need several WorkerBee and DroneBee, then set those properties to an Array, and put the Bees in the arrays.

Comment: And `Bee.id` doesn't make sense. The value of `this` in the constructor isn't referencing the function. Are you applying concepts from a different language here?

Comment: I am using id simply so that I can reference later in the code each type of bee (Worker or Drone, Queen is only one) I thought that by adding an id it would make easy to get hold of all of the bees with the same id

Comment: You're losing most of your Drones and Workers. If you wanted a master list of all Bees, then you can create an Array outside the constructor, and add them inside. Then you can iterate the array and check its `id`. Or if you have a particular object, you can just do `myBeeObject.id ===  2`.

Comment: You could also set up new constructors that inherit from `Bee.prototype`, so then you wouldn't even need the `.id`. You could just do `myBeeObject instanceof WorkerBee`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue the bee theme you could create a hive to which you can add bees, and return bees based on their `id`.

```
function Hive() {}

Hive.prototype.bees = [];

Hive.prototype.addBee = function (bee) {
  this.bees.push(bee);
};

Hive.prototype.getBeeIds = function (id) {
  if (!id) return this.bees;
  return this.bees.filter(function (bee) {
    return bee.id === id;
  });
}

var hive = new Hive();
```

To add a bee:

```
hive.addBee(new Bee('WorkerBee1', 2, 75, 12));
hive.addBee(new Bee('DroneBee1', 3, 50, 12));
```

To retrieve bees with a certain `id` call `getBeeIds` with an `id` parameter.

```
hive.getBeeIds(2);
```

To retrieve all bees call `getBeeIds` without an `id` parameter.

```
hive.getBeeIds();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ejwsxLsL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're trying to assign multiple objects to one key of an object. That will not work. You should use an array of objects instead. And to filter out the correct ones I would suggest the Array.filter() function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var BEES = [];

    BEES.push(new Bee('WorkerBee1',2,75,12);
    BEES.push(new Bee('WorkerBee2',2,75,12);
    BEES.push(new Bee('WorkerBee3',2,75,12);

    var selectedBees = BEES.filter(function(bee){
       return bee.id == 2;
    });

    console.log(selectedBees); //Should log Array of all 3 bees

});
```

The map function takes a callback function that is called for every single entry of the Array that you are filtering. If the function returnes true for a certain item it gets pushed into the final `selectedBees` Array. If false nothing happens.

**EDIT**

I used map instead of filter. Map works different, just saw the mistake and fixed it!